# couldn't understand specific line on code

Tags: python

hi guys I'm new to programming
while practicing I didn't understand the "a" variable line I'm leaving
the Code bellow thanks a lot.

```
I = 1
j = 2
while i >= 1:
    a = ""*j+"*"*i+""*j
    print(a)
    i = i + 2
    j = j - 1
    if i > 5:
        break
i = 3
j = 1
while i >= 1:
    a = ""*j+"*"*i+""*j
    print(a)
    i = i - 2
    j = j + 1
```

Comment: Did you try breaking it down to elements and printing them? Like `print(""*j)` or `print("*"*i)`?

Comment: Anyway this code is confusing for no reason because `""*j+"*"*i+""*j` is equivalent to `"*"*i`

Comment: yes sir I tried "*" * i  I got the first 3 step which are *. ***  *****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, the variable `a` is a string which is formed by the concatenation of: `j` times an empty space, `i` times the character `*`, and `j` times an empty space again. In this particular case then, the `j` part of the definition of `a` is useless, as the string is empty.

As you increase the value of `i` in your while loop, the number of times the character `*` (or any string for that matter) that will be attributed to `a` will increase.
That is why, when you run your code, you have at first one `*` printed, as `i = 1`. Further into the loop, you then add `2` to `i`, so that in the next iteration of your while loop, `i = 3`, so you then have `***` printed (see output below).

```
*
***
*****
***
*
```

But this string could be anything, so if you replace it by something else it would still work. For instance, if you replace `"*"` by `"banana"`, then the output of your code would be:

```
banana
bananabananabanana
bananabananabananabananabanana
bananabananabanana
banana
```

Comment: thanks sir, is there anyway to get this a variable cleaner? because its confusing

Comment: My pleasure! I do not know the purpose of this code, but a cleaner version would be a more pythonic approach I would say.
For instance, you could follow a PEP convention, like this one https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ (PEP 8). This gives some good suggestions on how to write readable code for others (including your future self ;)).

I would personally put some spaces around the `+` sign for readability, like such:

`a = ""*j + "*"*i + ""*j`
But I do not know what use you have of the j variable and its empty string, so just from this, I would remove it and write:
`a = "*"*i`

Answer (score 0):

This expression is used to multiply the strings. That means you can repeat the string n times. So for example if you write:

```py
2*'string'
```

You will get: `stringstring`. In your case repeat the space and the asterisk. You can simplify the expression by using the following line:

```py
a = "*"*i
```

Comment: thanks sir, but when I typed "*" * i   I only got the first 3 asterisk  line  maybe I need some more  code lines  to get the rest. I'm confused

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2140372&seqNum=4#:~:text=Multiplication) will help you.

Comment: thanks guys finally I got it I really appreciate it